# Is it considered bad form to delete a nonexistent record in Oracle?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, oracle

I see that I can "Delete" a record that doesn't exist with impunity; but are there any hidden dangers in this?

If it would be better to first check to see if the record exists, is there some ultra-fast way to do that?

IOW, is there a way to quickly perform this pseudo-SQL:

```
if recordExists(table, rowval[s])
  deleteRecord
```

?

Comment: Suggestion: begin transaction; delete; check the number of rows affected in the target table (perhaps deleting zero rows indicates an application error?); test for other effects (did a trigger or a foreign key's referential triggered action cause other tables to be affected? did an error occur?); if all is good then commit transaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, there's no real reason to check if something exists before you delete it.  SQL is a set-based language, it's perfectly valid to delete the elements of an empty set

To check if something exists requires a look-up and, at worst, you'll have to do the same lookup again to delete.  The only time that this is **good** form is when it's possible for the statement to cause an error if the condition isn't met (statements that modify the DDL come to mind)

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no reason to not use a normal DELETE statement to delete a row that may or may not be there:

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE Id = 234
```

This will either delete the specified row, or it won't.  In the former case, the update count will be 1 and in the latter case it will be 0.  You can use this to perform any additional logic in the case where the record did exist.

Answer (score 1):

So long as you are willing to accept the DELETE action if the record exists you are free to delete away - record or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, the other danger of performing an existence check prior to the "real" query is that the visible version of the data can change between queries unless you've taken the precaution of changing the read consistency to serializable.